# Difference between Object.assign and object spread

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

Having

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2};
```

What are the differences between

```
obj = Object.assign(obj, { c: 3});
```

And

```
obj = {...obj,  c: 3 };
```

Comment: Check [compiled version](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&code=obj%20%3D%20%7B...obj%2C%20%20c%3A%203%20%7D%3B) and [proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread)

Comment: OK, so the spread operator for object literals isn't ES6, while `Object.assign` is.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The difference is that when using a spread you are always creating a new object:

```js
const a = { name: 'Joe Bloggs' }
const b = { ...a, age: 27 };

console.log(a === b) //=> false
```

However using `Object.assign` it is possible to mutate an existing object:

```js
const a = { name: 'Joe Bloggs' }
const b = Object.assign(a, { age: 27 });

console.log(a === b) //=> true
```

You still can achieve the behaviour of an object spread with `Object.assign` by passing an empty object literal as the first argument:

```js
const a = { name: 'Joe Bloggs' }
const b = Object.assign({}, a, { age: 27 });

console.log(a === b) //=> false
```

Comment: Because you can't specify a target with object spread and thus can't mutate existing objects, it is actually safer than `Object.assign` and more consice.

Comment: **So object spreading is more preferable and safer than the `Object.assign`** @user6445533